# What is the difference between ADC sampling rate and data rate are they same or different

Tags: analog, adc

May I know the difference between ADC sampling rate and data rate .

If the sampling rate is 125Ksps,can I say data rate is also 125Ksps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADC data rate would be equal to the sampling rate for a 1-bit ADC : 125ksps = 125kbps. Not many 1-bit ADCs out there that I know off, so if you had a more common 16-bit ADC for instance, then your 125KSps will equal to 16 x 125 kBps = 2 Mbps data rate, and this, only for a mono channel - double it for stereo interleaved.

Comment: An edge triggered D-Flip-Flop is a one bit ADC.  :-)  (I just playing, but it is.)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy A comparator is a one-bit flash ADC!

Comment: That's the effective (useful) data rate.  The actual data rate of the ADC interface will be higher, to account for writing configuration registers, reading status bits, and possible command overhead reading the conversion results.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. Sure but that was not the original question. Regardless of ADC and vendor specific interface overheads, there is a standard data throughput that can be calculated, without knowing the detailed ADC's overheads that is vendor specific as you point out.

Comment: @citizen: The original question wasn't clear about what it is asking.  I think it's important to inform OP that more data is exchanged with the ADC than simply the conversion results.  And then there are ADCs which internally perform oversampling, filtering, and decimation.  Then the output data rate is actually lower than the sampling rate.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. Yes that's exactly right for vendor specific features that one may or may not want to use, but the basic sampling vs unprocessed data rate better be the same and predictable, in all cases regardless of vendor and it's particular features and or options etc. I think the question was very much of a general nature ...